# Click on a button and changes component in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm a newbie at VueJS 2, currently doing a project. I used Vue-Cli with webpack to create the project. I have difficulty in trying to get this part done. So basically, when i click a button, i want to change to another component.

After clicking the "Add Staff" button, i want to change the things in the red box to another component?

[Current Items in the Red Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHLGF.jpg)

[I want to replace this with the current items in the red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm3iE.png)

What is the best way of doing this? Having multiple templates in the Vue file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done a number of ways. The most basic way would be to use [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

```
data:{
  addStaff: false
}

<staff-listing v-if="!addStaff"></staff-listing>
<add-staff v-else></add-staff>
```

Or, you could use a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) with a `currentView` data property.

```
data:{
    currentView: "staff-listing"
}
```

And in the template

```
<component :is="currentView"></component>
```

Beyond those options you could use [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) for a full featured SPA navigation solution..